# Why does Phalcon 2 raise "undefined symbol: php_pdo_get_dbh_ce in Unknown on line 0" warning?

Tags: installation, warnings, phalcon

When I installed Phalcon 2.0.13 according to the https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html description and I wanted to launch my test script then I got the following error (literally it is just a warning but it causes Phalcon not to be loaded which causes errors):

{
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/phalcon.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_get_dbh_ce in Unknown on line 0
}

What is this symptom cased by and how could I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After struggling a lot, I managed to solve the problem. The `{extension=phalcon.so}` line should be put NOT in `php.ini`. Much rather, you should create a `/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/30-phalcon.ini` file containing `{extension=phalcon.so}`.

The reason is that this way you can guarantee that the processing order of the ini files is appropriate.

If you want to use Phantom not just in cli but in apache module as well then copy the ini file in the corresponding directory too.
(The directory names can be different in your system.)